# Django save and enter data after API call in views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 django project, D1 and D2. D1 has a table call T1 and D2 has a table call T2.

So i have a view in D1 that do api call to the api in D2 and save the value that i get after a POST request into T1. But i also want to be able to enter data in other field of table T1.

example: t2 only has `book` field, t1 has `book` and `author` field. When D1 do a post method to t2 in D2, it will return a `book` value which will be save into `t1` but i also want the user to enter the `author` themself. How do i do it ?

**Here is my code**

**models.py**

In D1:

```
class T1(models.Model):
    book = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

In D2

```
class T2(models.Model):
    book = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_django_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', data=request.POST)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', data=request.GET)

    if r.status_code == 201 and request.method == 'POST':
        data = r.json()
        testsave_attrs = {
            "book": data["book"],
        }
        testsave= T1.objects.create(**testsave_attrs)
        return HttpResponse(r.text)
    elif r.status_code == 200:  # GET response
        return HttpResponse(r.json())
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Could not save data')
```

Comment: Really, really, don't make POST requests from your app to itself.

Comment: What do you suggest then ? since it is using API from another project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can simply do it in the same POST request made to `my_django_view`. You can treat `request.POST` as a dictionary. It basically has key-value pairs of all the user inputs in the request and maybe stuff like your CSRF token. In any case, in your front-end, you'd want to have a form or something to send, together with your other existing `request.POST` data such that you can extract it out in your view.

```
@csrf_exempt
def my_django_view(request):

    author = None  # let author be None at the start

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_data = request.POST.copy()  # make a copy
        author = post_data.dict().pop("author", None)  # Extract out the author here and remove it from request.POST
        r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', data=post_data)
    else:
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/', data=request.GET)

    if r.status_code == 201 and request.method == 'POST':
        data = r.json()
        testsave_attrs = {
            "book": data["book"],
            "author": author
        }
        # You should probably do some validation that author is not None here
        # before you actually attempt to create T1.
        # You could do it here or anywhere else before creating T1.
        testsave= T1.objects.create(**testsave_attrs)
        return HttpResponse(r.text)
    elif r.status_code == 200:  # GET response
        return HttpResponse(r.json())
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Could not save data')
```

Comment: I got this error instead after trying it out. `raise AttributeError("This QueryDict instance is immutable")
AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable` This error occurs on this line `author = request.POST.pop("author", None)`

Comment: Ah yes, just make a copy - I've updated my answer, also take note that your requests.post needs to use the copied data too.

Comment: It works. But the result when viewing the T1 table api after saving, the author result seems weird. `"author": "['new']"` instead of `"author": "new"`

Comment: What did your data look like before saving - what does `author` return in the line `author = post_data.pop("author", None)`? And what's the full result that you see when you view T1?

Comment: This is the data before it save: `<QueryDict: {'book': ['new '], 'author': ['new']>`. This is the full result when viewing from api:     `{
        "id": 14,
        "book": "new",
        "author": "['new']"
    }`

Comment: I updated the answer, note the line `author = post_data.dict().pop("author", None)` - we need to convert it to a python dict first so that it'll extract if from a list. Django's [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#id1) is meant to retrieve multiple values of the same key, so everything will exist in a list. Since we're extracting it out ourselves, we need to remember to convert it to a python dictionary and Django will help you extract single values out of the lists.

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly now. Also thank you for the explanation